# HornetQ message redelivery behavior

Tags: jboss5.x, hornetq

Using HornetQ 2.1.2 with JBoss 5.1.0 GA

I'm facing with a rather odd problem .... that is, I'm receiving messages that have
been alreday been delivered . The messages are quite old (sent a couple of weeks ago) - were processed correctly -
and now they have been redelivered.

Any ideas on what might cause such behavior ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HornetQ configuration and verify (on the queue in question) the redelivery delay and the redelivery mulitplier.  Messages often are sent to your application in a XA transaction and can be rolled back onto the originating queue for a retry that after X number of seconds.